# I have a playlist of songs in youtube and I want to download all of them using Scrapy but I'm able to see the titles of only first 30

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a playlist of songs in [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com) that has more than 100 songs and I want to download all of them using Scrapy but I'm able to see the titles of only first 30 songs from the list.Please suggest me a way to fetch all the songs from my playlist.

Code so far:

```py
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Playlist_Scraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'find_playlist'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls =[
            'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tNU6dpjIyM&list=RD_tNU6dpjIyM',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.css('ahref').attrib['href'])
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl

Answer (score 0):

The contents of 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tNU6dpjIyM&list=RD_tNU6dpjIyM'

begin with some json meta data and if you for example search for 'somewhere' you will notice that the data for the link for "Linking park - Somewhere I belong" is there.
You just need to extract the exact line.

it is a script tag with the following structure:

```
<script >
window["ytInitialData"] = {"responseContext": "<data containing all the songs"....}
window["ytInitialPlayerResponse"] = {<more meta data not sure what is is for"}
</script>
```